# ultimate-seed restify puzzler

Tags: node.js, mongoose, crud, restangular

So I'm slowly concurring the ultimate-seed monster and have come across an issue that I can't seem to get past. If you're familiar with Pilwon's https://github.com/pilwon/ultimate-seed, it uses his https://github.com/pilwon/node-ultimate for automatically creating restful controllers from Mongoose schemas. I have added my own Model called `Company` and pretty much copied the User model to create the CRUD controller for the Company model. Here's the restify part -

```
// Restify
schema.restify = {
    'list': {
        'admin': '*',
        'user': '*'
    },
    'get': {
        'admin': '*',
        'user': '*'
    },
    'post': {
        'admin': '*'
    },
    'put': {
        'admin': '*',
        'user': '*'
    },
    'delete': {
        'admin': '*'
    }
};
```

In addition, I also added the following to routes.js -

```
restify.model('/api/company', 'Company');
```

Now, the GET api/company works fine, POST api/company gives the correct error when logged in as 'user' -

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Must be admin."
    },
    "result": null,
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "/api/company",
    "query": {}
}
```

but for some reason, PUT api/company gives the following error -

Cannot PUT /api/company

Can anyone who has worked with Ultimate-Seed help?

Thanks,

_K

Comment: Ok, using the REST Console on Chrome, I debugged the issue to Restangular on the Client side instead. Seems like company.put(); from the client side is not sending the correct REST request like api/company/:_id. Instead the request looks like api/company. Will post update once I have.

Comment: This is now resolved. Sort of. The issue was that I'm using Restangular with `Restangular.one('company').get({param:value}).then(function(company){ $scope.company = company[0]});`   which interestingly doesn't assign the right id of company to the Restangularized object and hence the company.put() call doesn't add the _id_ at the end of the URL. I worked around it with Restangular's customPUT() method where I can upend to the path with the _id_ manually. I think Restangular is one of the messiest module I've worked with.